# Different border radius

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic3

I'm using Highcharts JS on an Ionic 3 app, using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts).

I wanted to have different border radius on my bar chart, and I found [this plugin](https://github.com/highcharts/rounded-corners). I wanted to use this plugin in Ionic with my package, but I don't find a solution to work with it.

Do you have a solution ? I can change the plugin for border radius if needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the js file in the component and pass Highcharts to it like so:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import rounded from '../plugins/rounded-corner.js';
rounded(Highcharts)

plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderRadiusTopLeft: '50%',
            borderRadiusTopRight: '50%'
        }
    }
```

Stacblitz demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1dlv9